# how to custom graph use highchart library?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, highcharts

I have already made a custom graph using highchart. But it doesn't look same with design.

this is chart that i already custom
[image: this is chart that i already custom]

this is design that what i want

[image: this is design that what i want]

this is my code that i build using vue js,

```
    <template>
    <div>
        <div class="card">
            <Highcharts :options="options" />
            <!--<Highstock :options="options" />
            <Highmaps :options="options" />
            <HighchartsGantt :options="options" />-->
        </div>

    </div>
</template>

<script>
        import Datepicker from 'vuejs-datepicker';
        import moment from 'moment';
        import Highcharts from 'highcharts';
        import loadMap from 'highcharts/modules/map.js';
        import { genComponent } from 'vue-highcharts';
    
        loadMap(Highcharts);
    
        export default {
            name: "SummarySproutComponent",
            data: function() {
                return {
                    
                }
            },
            created() {
                this.getOption()
            },
            components: {
                Highcharts: genComponent('Highcharts', Highcharts),
                Highmaps: genComponent('Highmaps', Highcharts)
            },
            methods: {
                getOption(){
                    let color = {
                        '38,5': 'red',
                        '39': 'green',
                        '39,4': 'blue'
                    }
                    let dataColor = [
                        {
                            'name':'halo',
                            'value': '39,5',
                            'floatValue': 3.5
                        },
                        {
                            'name':'halo',
                            'value': '39,77',
                            'floatValue': 4
                        },
                        {
                            'name':'halo',
                            'value': '40',
                            'floatValue': 5
                        }
                    ]
                    let dataPlotlines = []
                    for(let i=0;i<dataColor.length;i++){
                        let dataPlotlinesLoop = {
                            color: '#FF0000',
                            width: 2,
                            value: dataColor[i].floatValue,
                            zIndex: 1.67,
                            label: {
                                // text: 'Plot line',
                                formatter: function () {
                                   return '<span>'+dataColor[i].value+'</span></br><img style="width:100px" src="https://img2.pngdownload.id/20180422/lpe/kisspng-microsoft-word-template-document-clip-art-61-clipart-5adce2aaedf920.7563442215244253869748.jpg" />';
                                },
                                verticalAlign: 'top',
                                align: 'right',
                                x: 15,
                                rotation: 0
                            }
                        }
                        dataPlotlines.push(dataPlotlinesLoop)
                    }
    
                    let colors = Highcharts.getOptions().colors
                    let optionStatic = {
                        chart: {
                            styledMode: true,
                            zoomType: 'xy'
                        },
                        title: {
                            text: 'Average Monthly Weather Data for Tokyo',
                            align: 'left'
                        },
                        subtitle: {
                            text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com',
                            align: 'left'
                        },
                        xAxis: [
                            {
                                categories: ['38,5', '39', '39,4', '39,5', '39,6', '39,77', '39,9', '40', '40,2', '40,4', '40,5', '41'],
                                plotLines:
                                dataPlotlines
                                ,
                                labels: {
                                    formatter () {
                                        return `<span style="color: ${color[this.value]}">${this.value}</span>`
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis
                            labels: {
                                format: '{value}°C',
                                style: {
                                    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2]
                                }
                            },
                            title: {
                                text: 'Temperature',
                                style: {
                                    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2]
                                }
                            },
                            opposite: true,
    
                        }, { // Secondary yAxis
                            title: {
                                text: 'Rainfall',
                                style: {
                                    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
                                }
                            },
                            labels: {
                                format: '{value} mm',
                                style: {
                                    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
                                }
                            }
    
                        },],
    
                        tooltip: {
                            shared: true
                        },
                        legend: {
                            layout: 'vertical',
                            align: 'left',
                            x: 80,
                            verticalAlign: 'top',
                            y: 55,
                            floating: true,
                            backgroundColor:
                                Highcharts.defaultOptions.legend.backgroundColor || // theme
                                'rgba(255,255,255,0.25)'
                        },
                        plotOptions: {
                            spline: {
                                // lineWidth: 4,
                                marker: {
                                    enabled: false
                                }
                            },
                            plotLines:{
                                dataLabels: {
                                    enabled: true,
                                    color: '#000000',
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        series: [{
                            name: 'Rainfall',
                            type: 'column',
                            yAxis: 1,
                            data: [0,0,0,1,2,6,2.5,1.8,0,0,0,0],
                            tooltip: {
                                valueSuffix: ' mm'
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            name: 'Temperature',
                            type: 'areaspline',
                            data: [0,10,40,80],
                            tooltip: {
                                valueSuffix: ' °C'
                            },
                            marker: {
                                enabled: false
                            },
                        },
                        {
                            name: 'Temperature',
                            type: 'spline',
                            // type: 'areaspline',
                            data: [0,10,40,80,150,280,150,80,40,10,0,0],
                            tooltip: {
                                valueSuffix: ' °C'
                            },
                            marker: {
                                enabled: false
                            }
                        }
                        ],
                        responsive: {
                            rules: [{
                                condition: {
                                    maxWidth: 500
                                },
                                chartOptions: {
                                    legend: {
                                        floating: false,
                                        layout: 'horizontal',
                                        align: 'center',
                                        verticalAlign: 'bottom',
                                        x: 0,
                                        y: 0
                                    },
                                    yAxis: [{
                                        labels: {
                                            align: 'right',
                                            x: 0,
                                            y: -6
                                        },
                                        showLastLabel: false
                                    }, {
                                        labels: {
                                            align: 'left',
                                            x: 0,
                                            y: -6
                                        },
                                        showLastLabel: false
                                    }, {
                                        visible: false
                                    }]
                                }
                            }]
                        }
                    }
                    this.options = optionStatic
                },
                genComponent(name, Highcharts) {}
            }
        }
    </script>
```

This is my first try making custom chart using highchart with a difficult pattern. I have already tried my best to make that design match with required one. I am still learning javascript and css (with the framework(vue)). I request someone to please help me to solve that problem.

Comment: First of all - do you use the official Highcharts Vue wrapper which is fully supported by Highcharts? https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-vue I can see the difference between those two images, but could you point out what exactly do you need to change? Should the rendered chart be the same as in the image? We can start from this simplified demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/gyp1qxv2/

Comment: @SebastianWędzel i'm not use official highchart for vue. What i want is make vertical line like image design what i wang above and hide one tooltip (the shaded part)

Comment: Something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/0y42gfpa/

Comment: @SebastianWędzel thanks for response and sorry for late response from me. can highchart show value info of vertical line like the design what i want (have square with arrow)?

Comment: You can set the `useHTML: true` for each label which renders those labels as outstanding HTML elements and you can customize their styling by CSS. API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.useHTML

Comment: @SebastianWędzel thanks for reference. i want ask one more question. the tooltip, how to hide tooltip (have shaded part)? thanks

Comment: You can use the `pointFormatter` callback to customize what the tooltip displays. https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.pointFormatter

Comment: @SebastianWędzel thanks a lot

Comment: @SebastianWędzel can you check my new posting (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66502800/how-to-make-the-realtime-chart-back-to-normal-after-hit-new-api)?. I got new problem, thanks

Comment: No worries, our support team will take care of your issue.