# how to make the realtime chart back to normal after hit new api

Tags: javascript, vue.js, highcharts, real-time

i already built realtime char using highchart in vuejs, it works properly. But if i hit new api, the chart run not like as it should be.

this is the picture of result while work properly :
[image]

this is the picture of result while i hit new api :
[image]

this is my code

sample api 1:

```
let result = [{"weight":40.2,"order":1},{"weight":39.85,"order":2},{"weight":41.8,"order":3},{"weight":40.05,"order":4},{"weight":40.05,"order":5},{"weight":40.2,"order":6},{"weight":41.8,"order":7},{"weight":40.05,"order":8},{"weight":40.05,"order":9},{"weight":40.35,"order":10}];
```

sample api 2:

```
let result = [{"weight":40.05,"order":11},{"weight":39.9,"order":12},{"weight":40.05,"order":13},{"weight":40.35,"order":14},{"weight":40.25,"order":15},{"weight":40.45,"order":16},{"weight":40.05,"order":17},{"weight":40.05,"order":18},{"weight":40.35,"order":19},{"weight":40.25,"order":20}]
```

highchart realtime config :

```
let optionStatic = {
chart: {
    height: 150,
    styledMode: true,
    type: 'spline',
    enderTo: 'chartRealTimeView',
    animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE
    marginRight: 10,
    events: { //used
       load: this.updateEvent()
    },
    backgroundColor: {
      linearGradient: [0, 0, 500, 500],
      stops: [
        [0, 'rgb(255, 255, 255)'],
        [1, 'rgb(200, 200, 255)']
      ]
    },
  },
  time: {
    useUTC: false
  },
  title: {
    text: ''
  },
  accessibility: {
    announceNewData: {
      enabled: true,
      minAnnounceInterval: 15000,
      announcementFormatter: function (allSeries, 
                                        newSeries, 
                                        newPoint) {
        if (newPoint) {
          return 'New point added. Value: ' + 
            newPoint.y;
        }
        return false;
      }
    }
  },
  xAxis: {},
  yAxis: {
    title: {
      text: ''
    },
    plotLines: [{
      value: 0,
      width: 1,
      color: '#fff'
    }],
    tickAmount: 3
  },
  tooltip: {
    headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br/>',
    pointFormat: 
    'order = {point.x:.2f}<br/>weight = {point.y:.2f}'
  },
  legend: {
    enabled: false
  },
  exporting: {
    enabled: false
  },
  series: [{
    name: '',
    data: (function () {
      // generate an array of random data
      // let time = (new Date()).getTime()
      let dataArr = []
      let l=0
      for (let lo = -4; lo <= 0; lo += 1) {
        if(l<result.length){
          dataArr.push({
            x: result[l].order,
            y: result[l].weight
          });
        }
        l++
      }
      return dataArr;
    }())
  }]
```

};

events code for handle realtime chart :

```
async updateEvent(){  
  this.flag == false    
  let incOffset = 0
  let offsetLoop = 2
  this.loopSeriesEvent(incOffset,offsetLoop)},

async loopSeriesEvent(incOffset=0,offsetLoop=2)
{
if(this.flag == false){
  incOffset = 0
  offsetLoop = 2
}
let getHitDetailApi = await this.hitDetailApi(offsetLoop)
let result = await fetch(getHitDetailApi)
if (result.ok) {
  this.flag=true
  let dataApi = await result.json();
  let newDataApi = dataApi.data.graph
  let series = this.chart.series[0]
  if(incOffset <= 4){
    let point = [newDataApi[incOffset].order, 
    newDataApi[incOffset].weight];
    // add the point
    series.addPoint(point, true, true);
    // series.redraw();
  }
  var that = this;
  setTimeout( function () {
    if(this.flag == false){
      incOffset = 0
      offsetLoop = 2
    }
    if(incOffset <= 4){
      incOffset += 1
    }else{
      incOffset = 0
      offsetLoop += 1
    }
    that.loopSeriesEvent(incOffset,offsetLoop);
  }, 3000)
}
return true}
```

can someone help me to find solution?

Comment: Hi @Hendri Sildrian, Could you reproduce the problem in some online code editor? You can start from: https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-vue-demo-ttner

Comment: @ppotaczek thanks for response and forgive me for late response. That problem already fixed. My team change scenario for realtime graph. My team use realtime database from firebase, so i just get and listen data from firebase